# Объединить 3 одномерных массива в 1 многомерный

Tags: php, php7

Есть 3 одномерных массива

```
Array
(
   [2] => World
   [3] => World
   [4] => United States
   [17] => United States
   [23] => United States
   [28] => United States
)
Array
(
   [2] => Short Football 4x4
   [3] => Short Football 4x4
   [4] => National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)
   [17] => National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)
   [23] => National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA). Women
   [28] => National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)
)
Array
(
   [2] => 334595637
   [3] => 334596291
   [4] => 334590962
   [17] => 334591241
   [23] => 334591994
   [28] => 334591016
)
```

В первом страны, во втором лиги, в третьем матчи.
Ключ у всех совпадает, то есть, матч "334595637", например, принадлежит лиге "Short Football 4x4", а та соответственно стране "World".

Требуется объединить данные массивы в 1, чтобы вышло вроде этого:

```
Array
(
   [United States] => Array
      ( 
         [National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)] Array
                                                        (
                                                               [0] => 334590962
                                                               [1] => 334591241
                                                        )
         [National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA). Women] Array
                                                        (
                                                               [0] => 334591994
                                                        )
      )
   [World] => Array
      ( 
         [Short Football 4x4] Array
                          (
                               [0] => 334595637
                               [1] => 334596291
                          )
      )
)
```

Страна одна, в ней может быть несколько лиг, в каждой из которой может быть несколько матчей.

Пока удалось объединить только страны-лиги, лиги-матчи:

```
$country_league = array();
foreach($country as $k => $v){
    $country_league[$v][]=$leagues[$k];
}

$league_match = array();
foreach($leagues as $k => $v){
    $league_match[$v][]=$matches_array[$k];
}
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$country = array
(
   2 => "World",
   3 => "World",
   4 => "United States",
   5 => "United States",
   6 => "United States",
   7 => "United States"
);
$leagues = array
(
   2 => "Short Football 4x4",
   3 => "Short Football 4x4",
   4 => "National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)",
   5 => "National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)",
   6 => "National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA). Women",
   7 => "National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)"
);
$matches = array
(
   2 => 334595,
   3 => 334596291,
   4 => 334590962,
   5 => 334591241,
   6 => 334591994,
   7 => 334591016
);
```

Сначала объединяем лиги-матчи

```
$league_match = array();    
foreach($matches as $k => $v){
     $league_match[$leagues[$k]][]=$v;
}
```

Потом добавляем лиги в страны:

```
$country_league = array();
foreach($leagues as $k => $v){
      $country_league[$country[$k]][$v]=$league_match[$v];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!